# React and Chart.js displaying fetched data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am having a problem understanding how I can get fetched data to be displayed on a chart using chart.js

```
const [backendData, setBackendData] = useState([{}])

useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/get').then((response) =>{
    console.log(response)
    setBackendData(response.data)
    })
}, [])

backendData.map((val) => {
    const total = val.total
})

mondayData.datasets.data = total

// monday chart data
var mondayData = {
    labels: ["7 AM", "8 AM", "9 AM", "10 AM", "11 AM", "12 PM", "1 PM", "2 PM", "3 PM"],
    datasets: [{
        data: [2, 1, 1, 6, 4, 7, 8, 14, 13],
        label: "Empty parking spaces",
        backgroundColor: "rgb(39, 63, 150, 0.5)",
    }]
}
// monday chart options
var mondayOptions = {

}



useEffect(() => {
    // var test = document.getElementById("0").getContext('2d');
    // test.destroy();
    // monday chart
    
    var mondayCtx = document.getElementById('mondayChart').getContext('2d');
    let mondayChartStatus = Chart.getChart("mondayChart");
    if (mondayChartStatus != undefined) {
        mondayChartStatus.destroy();
    }
    var mondayChart = new Chart(mondayCtx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: mondayData
    });
```

The backendData variable has one value {total: 22} which is pulled from the database
which is then (I think) getting used to set the const total variable

Right now what I am trying to do is get the 22 to be displayed as the first value on the chart.

I am using the mondayData.datasets[0].data = total to access it but I get an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'datasets')"

I just want to use my fetched data from a database to be used as the data for the chart